# "in which people study" or "where people study on"

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, relative-pronouns, pied-piping

Should it be:

> Campus is a place in which children study.

**or**

> Campus is a place where children study on.

Which one is correct, or are they both incorrect? Why?

Is there a better version?

Comment: I think it should be: *Campus is a place where children study.* **or** *Campus is a place where children go to study* I am not 100% sure, but the first option seems right to me.

Comment: I think your versions are both right.

Comment: @dennylv The second example is wrong ...

Comment: @Araucaria OP's right? or mine, too?

Comment: @Usernew Yours are both ok, but you need the word *a* at the beginning?

Comment: @Araucaria you mean before "campus"? I think there is a need for *a* at the beginning. *A campus is a place where children study.*

Comment: @Usernew Yes that's right! See my new answer ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Locative Adjuncts**

- She plays football in the park

In the sentence above, the Subject is *she* and the Object is *football*. What is that bit at the end, *in the park*? It is a Locative Adjunct (sometimes called a "Locative Adverbial"). It gives us extra information about *where* something happens.

Usually, Locative Adjuncts are preposition phrases. In the sentence above the Locative Adjunct is a preposition phrase *in the park*. The Head of the preposition phrase is the preposition *in*. This preposition has a noun phrase as a Complement. The noun phrase inside the preposition phrase is *the park*.

**The relative words *which* and *where***

We use the word *where* to represent Locative Adjuncts. We use the word *which* to replace Subjects, Objects or Complements of Prepositions. Adjuncts are usually preposition phrases. Subjects, Objects and preposition Complements are usually noun phrases.

**Relative clauses**

We often use relative clauses to modify nouns. So we have a main noun, the antecedent, and then we have a relative clause which comes afterwards:

- This is **the park** [where Jane plays football].
- This is **the park** [which Jane plays football in].

In the sentences above the antecedent is the noun phrase *the park*, the relative clause is the bit in brackets, [ ]. Let's look at the relative clauses.

These clauses have a *wh-* word at the beginning. They also have a gap in them:

- where Jane plays football ______
- which Jane plays football in _____

We understand that the *wh-* word represents that gap at the end. We can model the grammar like this:

- **where** Jane plays football [ **<del>in the park</del>** ]
- **which** Jane plays football in [ **<del>the park</del>** ]

If we look at the sentences above, we can see that *where* replaces the whole Locative Adjunct. It replaces the whole preposition phrase, the preposition *and* the noun.

In contrast, *which* only replaces the Complement of the preposition. It doesn't replace the preposition itself. We need to keep the preposition in the clause.

We have two choices about what we can do with this preposition that isn't replaced. We can either leave it where it is, or we can move it to the beginning of the relative clause. If we do this it appears in front of it's complement, the word *which*:

- which she plays football in.
- in which she plays football.

The second sounds quite formal. The first can be used in both formal and informal speech and writing.

**The Original Poster's examples**

> 1. A campus is a place in which children study.
> 2. *A campus is a place where children study in. (ungrammatical)

Campus is a countable noun, so we need to use the word *a* with it. Also, we do indeed study on a campus. However, the antecedent noun, the noun which is being modified, is *place*, not campus. We study on a campus, but *in* a place, so we definitely need the preposition *in*.

In example (1), the writer has kept the preposition *in*. They have only replaced the Complement of the preposition, a noun phrase. Because of this, they have used the word *which*. This is correct. We use which to replace noun phrases like this.

In example (2), the writer has used *where*. This means they should replace the whole Locative Adjunct. They need to delete the whole preposition phrase, not just the noun. So we don't want to see the preposition *in* here. The sentence should look like this:

- A campus is a place where children study.

We can understand the sentence like this:

- A campus is a place where children study [ <del>in the place</del> ].

The writer has three options then. They can use any of the following:

- A campus is a place where children study. [preposition phrase deleted]
- A campus is a place which children study in. [preposition left at end]
- A campus is a place in which children study. [preposition moved to front]

*Hope this is helpful!*

**Note:**

In case the Original Poster is going to use this sentence, we usually think about a campus as being part of a college or university, we don't use this word very much for schools where there are younger children. We might want to swap the word *children* for *students* or *young people* perhaps.

Comment: Very well summed up. +1 for a thorough explanation. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the very helpful answer.I'd like to ask if the  sentence "Campus is a place children study at (or in)", as in said the answer below,  is correct and implies the same meaning as the sentences you mentioned in your answer :)

Comment: @Mrt Thank you. "A campus is a place children study in" is grammatical. The reason is, it is  reduced form of "A campus is a place **which** children study in". When *which* is not the subject of the restrictive relative clause, we can delete it. [However, * "A campus is a place **where** children study in" is, of course, ungrammatical, because *where* must replace the whole locative adjunct]. Does that answer your query? :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you. I think I got it but I am still confused about a related sentences which is " This is the place/house I live (in)" ..I think I can say "This is the house where I live / this is the house in which I live / this is the house which I live in " ..is it ok to say " This is the house I live"  because I think I saw this sentence before..

Comment: @Mrt You can't say "This is the house I live". That's definitely not grammatical. (When the word *place* is an antecedent however, things get very complicated. You *can* say: "This is the place we met last time" for example. But the word *place* is unique in English. It has completely different rules. Maybe you heard a *place* sentence?)

Comment: @Araucaria Hi, could you explain your sentence ( When which is not the subject of the restrictive relative clause, we can delete it ) please ..this is one of topics that confused me. I know that if the subject in main clause is object of the relative clause , then it cannot be omitted. For example : "My mother, who / whom you met yesterday, wants to talk to you." ...We cannot say 
"My mother you met yesterday wants to talk to you"... The one you refer to is the same thing? Can you explain to me please or send  a link which explains

Comment: @Mrt Your example has to do with the RC not being restrictive. A 'restrictive' relative clause usually explains which thing we are talking about and is necessary to identify that thing. A non-restrictive relative clause jsut gives you more information about the thing you are talking about. So in your example, we know who your mother is (because you have only one!), so the relativ clause is non-restrictive. We cannot delete the *wh*-word in a *non*-restrictive relative clause.

Comment: @Mrt When the clause *is* restrictive, you can delete *who(m)* or *which* if it isn't the Subject of the relative clause. An easy trick to learn is this. If there is another noun phrase (including pronouns) before the verb, you can delete the relative word. So you can delete it in "the man who **you met**" because we have the word *you* before the verb *meet*. You cannot delete it in "the man who likes you" because there is no other noun or pronoun before the verb *likes*. Does that help?

Comment: @Mrt Notice that if you had *two* mothers for some special reason, then you *could* delete *who* in your example: "*My mother you met yesterday lives in France, but my other mother lives in Austalia*"

Comment: @Araucaria I got your first 2 messages very well but Id like to ask in my first example if I change the subject for any " woman" and makes the relative clause restrictive ( or defining) then , can I omit the relative pronoun?  "The woman who you met yesterday wants to talk you" ...can I say "The woman you met yesterday wants to talk you"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38045/discussion-between-mrt-and-araucaria).

Answer (score 1):

> Campus is a place in which children study.

means the same thing as

> Campus is a place where children study.

Now, if you add 'on' at the end, you're changing the meaning:

> Campus is a place, where children study **on**.

This is the same form as *going on* versus *going* - it means insistent, ceaseless continuation. It's not that children dedicate the regular amount of time to studying, but that they keep studying way longer than they should - e.g. failing to pass to the next class, and repeating their classes.

I believe you might have confused it with the following:

> Campus is a place children study **at** *(or **in**)*.

Moving the preposition to the end of the sentence is correct, though discouraged practice. In this case this is equivalent to the "at which", or "in which" construction.